# pivoting LINQ containing special characters (like plus or minus) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, pivot-table

Suppose I have the following table

    `name testID Value
    John Glu    4.3
    John Ket    2.1
    John Cl-    3.2
    Mary Glu    4.3
    Mary Na+    4.2
    Mary Cl-    6.9
    Pete Na+    N/A
    Pete Cl-    3.1`


The LINQ query should pivot as follows

    `` Name  Glu Ket Na+ Cl-
    John  4.3 2.1 NUL 3.2
    Mary  4.3 NUL 4.2 6`.9
    Pete  NUL NUL N/A 3.1 ``

Whilst I understand how this can be done with `SQL`, but I have no clue how to do this with `LINQ` (especially `if` field containing plus, underscore or minus signs)
First of all, I was wondering if this is even possible do this in `LINQ` (with plus or minus signs) with `VB.NET`, if so can someone point us to the right direction please?

Many thanks

**EDITED**

The linq I wrote kind of half works without the Na+ or Cl- part:

```
 from f in (from r in results group r by r.name into group )  _
 let a as object = _
 (From e in f.Group where e.testID= "Glu" select e.Value).max _
 let b as object = _
 (From e in f.Group where e.testID= "Ket" select e.Value).max _
 let c as object = _
 (From e in f.Group where e.testID= "Na+" select e.Value).max _
 let d as object = _
 (From e in f.Group where e.testID= "Cl-" select e.Value).max _
 select f.name, Glu = a, Ket = b, [Na+] = c, [Cl-] = d
```

substituting

```
      [Na+] = c , [Cl-] = d
```

with

```
     Na = c , Cl = d
```

it will work as expected, but is there a way have plus or minus sign display on the column header?